# Is it possible to wirelessly connect to dual monitors? What is required to do so?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, multiple-monitors, bluetooth

Is it possible to wirelessly cast to dual monitors? What does it require? Is it as simple as one hdmi casting dongle per monitor, then display manager>detect screen?

I'd like to extend my desktop with closed-lid, using both windows and mac laptops. I'd like to cast to dual monitors on a macbook pro (early 2015) and pc laptop (windows 10).

My dual monitors are connected to my home desktop (windows 7).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, yes, it is possible.  There are many wireless video transmission technologies.  Examples are [WirelessHD](http://www.wirelesshd.org/), [WHDI](http://www.whdi.org/), and [WiGig](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-certified-wigig).  There are also source specific systems like AirPlay Mirroring from Apple,  Google Cast from Google, Miracast from many companies, and WiDi from Intel.

Just google wireless HDMI and you can find a lot of hardware that way.